# Not allowed to start service Intent without permission not exported from uid

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentservice

Im trying to call a 3rd party service intent within my android app but it returns the error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.othercompany.SERVICE_INTENT flg=0x3 cmp=com.mycompany.package/com.othercompany.service.CoreService (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10107

**The service intent I am trying to call is completely external to my application and therefore I cannot access its code or manifest files.**

my code is as follows:

```
        buttonPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent talkButtonDown = new Intent(PRESS_CLASS);
            talkButtonDown.setClassName(PACKAGE, "com.othercompany.service.CoreService");
            talkButtonDown.putExtra(RESTART_EXTRA, true);
            talkButtonDown.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            talkButtonDown.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            startService(talkButtonDown);
        }
    });
```

I have read in other posts about needing 'exported=true' in the manifest of the external app, but I have no access to this manifest.
Is there anything else that could be throwing this error? Any help would be highly appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything else that could be throwing this error?

No. That service is not exported. It is exclusively for use by the app hosting the service, not for other apps to invoke directly.

You might consider contacting the company in question to see if they have a documented and supported API for working with their Android app.

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping that wasn't the case.
I'll contact the developer and make sure all is ok on their end.
Many Thanks.